# problems compiling mysql on ubuntu oneiric

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile mysql 5.1.60 on ubuntu oneiric. I'm not sure why its not compiling properly. I get this error using the bundled libedit/libreadline. Ive tried using the system libraries and I get errors with that as well.

EDIT: Tried compiling other versions of mysql and I get the same thing. I'm guessing its a change in oneiric ubuntu?

```
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_deletechars':
terminal.c:(.text+0x755): undefined reference to `tgoto'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_set':
terminal.c:(.text+0x1033): undefined reference to `tgetent'
terminal.c:(.text+0x104f): undefined reference to `tgetflag'
terminal.c:(.text+0x1064): undefined reference to `tgetflag'
terminal.c:(.text+0x1079): undefined reference to `tgetflag'
terminal.c:(.text+0x108e): undefined reference to `tgetflag'
terminal.c:(.text+0x10a3): undefined reference to `tgetflag'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o):terminal.c:(.text+0x10b8): more undefined references to `tgetflag' follow
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_set':
terminal.c:(.text+0x10cd): undefined reference to `tgetnum'
terminal.c:(.text+0x10e2): undefined reference to `tgetnum'
terminal.c:(.text+0x110c): undefined reference to `tgetstr'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_insertwrite':
terminal.c:(.text+0x18cf): undefined reference to `tgoto'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_move_to_char':
terminal.c:(.text+0x1b65): undefined reference to `tgoto'
terminal.c:(.text+0x1b80): undefined reference to `tgoto'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_move_to_line':
terminal.c:(.text+0x1cd5): undefined reference to `tgoto'
terminal.c:(.text+0x1d14): undefined reference to `tgoto'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_echotc':
terminal.c:(.text+0x288b): undefined reference to `tgetstr'
terminal.c:(.text+0x29a7): undefined reference to `tgoto'
terminal.c:(.text+0x29ca): undefined reference to `tgoto'
../cmd-line-utils/libedit/libedit.a(terminal.o): In function `terminal_tputs.isra.1':
terminal.c:(.text+0x535): undefined reference to `tputs'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mysql] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/mysql-5.1.60/client'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/mysql-5.1.60/client'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you compiling MySQL 5.1 for Oneiric, if packages are available?

```
$ apt-cache search mysql 5.1
[...]
mysql-client-5.1 - MySQL database client binaries
mysql-client-core-5.1 - MySQL database core client binaries
mysql-server-5.1 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-core-5.1 - MySQL database server binaries
[...]
```

If you really do want to compile it, I'd suggest looking at the build scripts for those packages (you can find them by doing `apt-get source mysql-5.1`, and looking in `debian/rules` and the rest of the `debian/` subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

cmake add this will work

-DCURSES_LIBRARY=/usr/local/ncurses/5.9/lib/libncurses.a \
-DCURSES_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/ncurses/5.9/include